# Is there any harm in "known incorrect sRGB profile" warning from dvips?

Tags: miktex, warnings, dvips

This is what I get from `stderr` stream when compiling with `lualatex` under MikTex 2.9:

```
This is dvips(k) 5.993 Copyright 2013 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com)
' TeX output 2014.06.27:1240' -> chart-autopp.ps
<d:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/dvips/base/tex.pro>
<d:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/dvips/misc/alt-rule.pro>
<d:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/dvips/pstricks/pstricks.pro>
<d:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/dvips/pstricks/pst-algparser.pro>
<d:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/dvips/pst-tools/pst-tools.pro>
<d:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/dvips/pstricks/pst-dots.pro>
<d:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/dvips/pst-barcode/pst-barcode.pro>
<d:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/dvips/base/special.pro>. [1] 
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
```

Are these warnings indicating that something needs to be corrected, or they can be ignored?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}
\begin{pspicture}(1.02in,1.02in)
    \psbarcode{http://localhost/Intranet/chart.aspx?id=10509110}{version=5}{qrcode}
\end{pspicture}
\end{adjustbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's due to a stricter checking introduced in the latest version of the `libpng` library, now used by `pdftex` and `luatex`; before the last updates they used `libpng 1.5.16`, now `libpng 1.6.10`. I don't know if it harms.

Comment: Some software will refuse to open or display images unless the 'error' is fixed. For example, GIMP. I don't know if this is likely to affect document viewers or not but the fact that it does not now do so should not be taken as reason to think it won't. You'd need to check whether the software is using an older version of the library which will eventually be updated, possibly triggering trouble.